# error message under TextInput in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have `TextInput` in my application.

I have taken `useState` for text input.

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
```

```
<TextInput
  style={[
    styles.input,
    { borderColor: !inputValue ? "red" : "#006d41" },
  ]}
  onChangeText={(text) => setInputValue({ oved: text })}
  value={inputValue}
  placeholder="Enter Employee ID"
  keyboardType="numeric"
  error={errorStatus}
/>
```

Below is the `onClick` button function  to go to `LoadingScreen`

```
<CompanyCardComponent
  companyName={item.name}
  goToHomeScreen={() => goToLoadingScreen(item.code)}
  randomColor={generateRandomCornerColor()}
/>
```

```
const goToLoadingScreen = (item) => {
  dispatch(changeCompany(item.toString(), inputValue.oved));
  props.navigation.navigate("LoadingScreen", { screen: LOADING_SCREEN });
};
```

[image]
**Description:--**

Upper three cards are the buttons and below is the `TextInput`.

I want to display an error message under the `TextInput` if I am not giving any input to the `TextInput`.

If I am not giving any input to the `TextInput` and click that button it won't proceed further and display one error message e.g. "please provide id" under the `TextInput`.

Comment: Where are you rending an error message in your code? Where do you disable the buttons from being clicked or ignore any clicks? Please update question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: check the question again..i want to display an error message but i have not rendering an error message